# Watch parent controller function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The part of my project is **component B** with `ng-repeat`, inside **component A**.
Both of component has a different controller (controller as).
In controller **component A**, created function like this:

```
this.functionName = function(){};
```

It is called when occurs event `ng-click`.

The essence of the question:
As in the controller of **component B**, perform some actions, every time when this function **(controller A)** is called?
I think I can somehow use the `$watch`, but I would like to do without something like `$scope.$parent.$parent.$watch;`

Comment: I'd rather use $broadcast/$emit to send messages and objects down/up and then on controller that receives message just put $scope.$on('somemessage', fn) You can never know that your component will stay on that place, and parent.parent really looks ugly if you ask me.

Comment: thx, I try use it.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use a service to share state between the two controllers.

Comment: @NikolajDamLarsen 

I already use the factory, but to get the data and describe the methods of working with this data. Can you tell me how it can be used for this task?

Comment: @Vitamine_R I've posted an answer with an example of how to use a service to share data between the components.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to using angular's eventsystem, you could use services to share the state between the components.

Here's an example *(I'm ignoring best practices here, to shorten the example)*:

```
app.service('myService', function(){
    var service = this;
    service.items = [];

    service.addItem = function(newItem){
        service.items.push(newItem);
    }
});

app.component('cmpA', {
    template: [
        '<ul>',
            '<li ng-repeat="item in $ctrl.items track by $index">{{item}}</li>',
        '</ul>'
    ].join(''),
    controller: function(myService){
        this.items = myService.items;
        console.log(this.items);
    }
});


app.component('cmpB', {
    template: [
        '<div>',
            '<input ng-model="$ctrl.newItem" /><button type="button" ng-click="$ctrl.save()">Save</button>',
        '</div>'
    ].join(''),
    controller: function(myService){
        this.newItem = '';
        this.save = function(){
            myService.addItem(this.newItem);
            this.newItem = '';
        }
    }
});
```

[You can see it in action in this plunker.](https://plnkr.co/edit/hffUpgRjdOzPP1dR1wT1?p=preview)

Hope this is something along the lines of what you need.

Comment: Sorry, but that's not it. You pass the data through the factory, but I need to track the call of the method in the other controller. I think the option suggested by @pegla will be the best.

Comment: No problem. You usually use callbacks to react to function calls, not a watch, so I may have just misunderstood your problem, to be related to sharing data between components. You could register a callback function in the service, but using broadcasts works just as well. I just generally dislike using broadcasts because it makes it slightly harder to reason about what happens in the application.